# How can I modify this projectile class to support movement in an arbitrary direction?

Tags: xna, direction

Hi I have the following class which Updates and Draws a projectile:

```
public class TierOneProjectile : IProjectile
{
    private AnimatedTexture animation;
    private Vector2 screenPosition, framesPerSecond, origin;
    private float rotation, scale, depth;
    private int velocity;

    public TierOneProjectile(Vector2 _screenPosition,int _velocity,AnimatedTexture _animation)
    {
        screenPosition = _screenPosition;
        animation = _animation;
        velocity = _velocity;
    }

    public void Update(float elapsedGameTime) 
    {
        animation.UpdateFrame(elapsedGameTime);
        screenPosition.X -= velocity;

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) 
    {
        animation.DrawFrame(spriteBatch,screenPosition);
    }

    public Rectangle getBoundingBox() 
    {
        return new Rectangle((int)screenPosition.X, (int)screenPosition.Y, (int)animation.GetTextureWH().X, (int)animation.GetTextureWH().Y);
    }
}
```

Currently the projectile alway flies to the left. Little did I know when I created this class. Now I want to pass a direction to the constructor so every projectile could fly into a different direction. What would be the smartest solution for this? I do not want you to write the code for me. But maybe you could give me a hint how this could be done.

Comment: I don't understand. You know exactly what you want to do, you've mentioned a way of doing it, and you don't want someone to write the code for you. Why aren't you trying to implement it the way you think it should be done? This doesn't seem like a gamedev question, it seems like a programming question.

Comment: @Byte56 Because I am looking for the smartest and cleanest solution ;)

Comment: Please define "smartest and cleanest" ;) In this case there's practically no room for smart/clean optimizations - you just code in 30sec it and that's it.

Comment: Just as an example. Simply out of unknowing I defined all velocity variables in my project as int. Maybe it would have been smarter to make'em float or Vector2. I'm inexperienced ;)

Comment: Oh cmon dat downvote, really?

Comment: Velocities can be `int`, I don't see a problem with that )

Comment: Ideally you'd simply ask "How do I move a projectile?" or something along those lines. Showing us what you've tried already and what you think is not smart or unclean about it. Give us an idea of the path you're headed down and exactly what problems you're facing. As you can see by Krom's answer, the code you included isn't required to answer. Further, there are a number of projectile questions on the site that have almost exactly the same code that's provided in Krom's answer, a little searching around first would have answered your question.

Comment: @Byte56 You could have for example told me that 'velocity.x * elapsedGameTime' would be a smarter way to implement the class, as this would make the animations equally fast/slow no matter on which machine it runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have now is essentially:

```
screenPosition.X -= velocity * 1.0;
screenPosition.Y -= velocity * 0.0;
```

You need to explicitly add a `Direction` variable which is a 2D vector (you are dealing with 2D, right?).

```
Direction = (1.0, 0.0);
```

You might be already seeing my lead. You need to scale `Velocity` by `Direction` and add to your `Position` like so:

```
screenPosition.X -= velocity * Direction.X;
screenPosition.Y -= velocity * Direction.Y;
```

Adding parameter to a constructor and a new field to the class is trivial.

P.S. I don't think there's anything smarter than simplicity in this case ;)